# Issue with aggregating data when data missing on certain dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join, data-analysis

How can I edit the following SQL query to get results for each day and each variant, where I have an A/B/Control test:

```
SELECT 
    t.day, t.type AS variant_type, t.clicks, 
    t2.type AS control, t2.control_clicks
FROM 
    table1 t
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 t2 ON t.day = t2.day
              AND t2.type = 'control'
```

Currently data will only come through where there is data for a given day in the from clause. This leads to issues when aggregating the data further down the line.

Current results:

| day | variant | variant_clicks | control | control_clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | a | 1000 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-01 | b | 2000 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-01 | control | 1500 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-02 | control | 1700 | control | 1700 |

Desired results:

| day | variant | variant_clicks | control | control_clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | a | 1000 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-01 | b | 2000 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-01 | control | 1500 | control | 1500 |
| 2020-01-02 | a | 0 | control | 1700 |
| 2020-01-02 | b | 0 | control | 1700 |
| 2020-01-02 | control | 1700 | control | 1700 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join` and then bring in existing data using `left join`:

```
SELECT d.day, v.type as variant_type,
       COALESCE(t.clicks, 0) as clicks, 'control' as control,
       MAX(t.clicks) FILTER (WHERE type = 'control') OVER (PARTITOIN BY d.day) as control_clicks
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT day FROM table1) d CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES ('a', 'b', 'control')) v(type) LEFT JOIN
     table1 t
     ON t.day = d.day AND t.type = v.type;
```

Note:  This uses window functions to get the control clicks rather than a separate aggregation and `join`.

Comment: Thank you for this @marc_s. Had thought of using a cross join for the days, just then wasn't sure what to do next

Do you know if there's a way to do it without specifying the values?

As I run tests with a differing number of variants - i.e. Control/A, Control/A/B/.../n,
A/B/C (where we would use A in place of the control group)?

Comment: @CharlieB . . . You can use a subquery . . . `(select distinct type from table1)`.